# Teradata: if field is not null, add next two rows of specific column to total

Tags: sql, grouping, teradata

Hi everyone -

```
ID          TOTAL          QTY 
111         NULL           100  
112         NULL           150  
113         312.00         70  
114         NULL           200 
115         14.00          40 
116         NULL           70  
117         NULL           100  
118         NULL           170
```

I'm trying to figure something relatively complicated out using Teradata.  In the data above, I want to create a new column called THREEDAY.  If TOTAL is null, then I want THREEDAY to equal the amount in QTY.  If TOTAL is not null, however, I want TOTAL to equal the amount in QTY **plus** the amount in QTY for the following two rows.  For example:

```
ID          TOTAL          QTY          THREEDAY
111         NULL           100          100
112         NULL           150          150
113         312.00         70           310
114         NULL           200          200
115         14.00          40           210
116         NULL           70           70
117         NULL           100          100
118         NULL           170          170
```

For ID 113, the amount in THREEDAY is 310 (70+200+40), and for ID 115, the amount is 210 (40+70+100).  For the rest of the IDs, the amount in THREEDAY equals QTY because the value in TOTAL is missing.

My skills are not up to par to tackle this kind of problem, so any assistance would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried so far in order to get proper help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `sum()` to do this. The solution assumes the ordering is based on `id` column. (This solution works in SQL Server. I assume this would work in Teradata too, if it doesn't it would require a syntax change)

```
select id,total,quantity,
case when total is null then quantity 
else sum(coalesce(quantity,0)) over(order by id rows between current row and 2 following)
end threeday
from tablename
```

[**`Sample example`**](http://rextester.com/KJHX95136)